# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticateResult' from assembly 'Microsoft.Owin...'

Tags: c#, owin, katana

Incase this hasn't been asked & answered, I think I've discovered a glitch in Katana/OWIN 2.1.

If you're using .NET 4.5 you may be encountering the error on the title line.

This is a workaround I've found:

Brute force the reference in the CSPROJ for Microsoft.Owin to point to .NET 4.0, since .NET 4.5 2.1 code omits the AuthenticateResult class.  3.0 brings it back again.  Evidenced [[http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/Project/Microsoft.Owin/2.0.0-rtw2-20822-585-rel/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Microsoft.Owin/Microsoft.Owin/Security/AuthenticateResult.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Owin]](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/Project/Microsoft.Owin/2.0.0-rtw2-20822-585-rel/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Microsoft.Owin/Microsoft.Owin/Security/AuthenticateResult.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Owin%5d)

This does appear to work, although I think it's causing a problem with app shutdown.

Is there a better way than what I've done?